# Django DRF restrict profile model creation to authenticated user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a many User model and a Customer model with a OneToOne relation to the User.
I have established authentication for User model where a user can edit/update/delete only his profile. But I want the customer model also to be accessible (list/create/update etc) by the authenticated user.

My permissions class for Customer:

```
class UpdateCustomerProfile(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow customers to edit their own profile """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """Check if user is authenticated and has permisson to access customer model """

        if view.action == 'list':
            return request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser
        elif view.action == 'create':
            return request.user.is_authenticated
        elif view.action in ['retrieve', 'update', 'partial_update', 'destroy']:
            return request.user.is_authenticated
        else:
            return False
```

My customer view set:

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handle creating reading and updating Users in  system"""

    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
    queryset = models.Customer.objects.filter()
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateCustomerProfile,)
```

But I get an error saying:

> "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

even If I add the token in Authorisation field of Header.

**UPDATE:**

If I add `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)` to my CustomerViewSet I get an error:

> ```
> "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
> ```

I'm confused, I want to leverage the current authorisation of an User to authorise creation of a customer. i.e Only An authenticated user should be able to create his Customer profile

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add authentication_classes attribute to the view

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handle creating reading and updating Users in  system"""

    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
    queryset = models.Customer.objects.filter()
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateCustomerProfile,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

Comment: I have tried that But I get "You do not have permission to perform this action." error if I add TokenAuthentication to CustomerViewSet. Just to clarify I have TokenAuthentication added to my UserViewSet and also a LoginViewSet which generates a token for user

Comment: the message "You do not have permission to perform this action" is returned from your `UpdateCustomerProfile` class. According to that class, you dont have the permission

Comment: Please add `UpdateCustomerProfile` class for further proceedings

Comment: I have already added `UpdateCustomerProfile` in the question. Please check

Comment: for testing purpose, add **`return True`** in **`has_permission()`** method and remove your conditions

Comment: okay I've figured out the problem it's because of the check for `request.user.is_superuser` if action is `list` which is intended but that is getting applied to create action also. if I remove `request.user.is_superuser` check in `list` if condition then API is accessible. How can I fix this?

Comment: that's weird!! Are you sure the permission denied while POST request also?

Comment: I did not explicitly try POST in postman. But  the post form disappeared in browsable API view. However I found a workaround, I removed that superuser check from permissions and moved it to the viewset (overriding list method)